Expired residence permit with valid long term visa
I have an Italian long term D type visa (300 days) valid till 9th of January, 2025. However, the residence permit issued to me  expired in November 2024. The residence permit was issued on the basis of my exchange program only for 9 months. Is it normal if I live in Italy until my long term visa expires? I cannot renew my residence permit as my program is complete.

From the EU visa code

If a visa is annulled or revoked, a stamp stating ‘ANNULLED’ or ‘REVOKED’ shall be affixed to it and the optically variable feature of the visa sticker, the security feature ‘latent image effect’ as well as the term ‘visa’ shall be invalidated by being crossed out.
A decision on annulment or revocation of a visa and the reasons on which it is based shall be notified to the applicant by means of the standard form set out in Annex VI.

When you got your residence permit, was your long term visa modified, like crossed or had a stamp "CANCELLED"?
if not it's still valid even if you got a residence permit in the meantime.

Hii and thanks for your answer. I received the permit on 2nd December, 2 days after its expiry. There was no modification done in my visa whatsoever. I booked my flights back to India for 6th Jan, 2025 (3 days before visa expires) long before I had received my permit. I was concerned if these days after November will be counted as overstay.

This is a national visa, it is not governed by the Schengen visa code.

But is it fine if I stay in Italy till the validity of visa, given that the permit is expired.
